# javapoet how to specify current generated instance as return result

Tags: code-generation, javapoet

I am writing an annotation Processor that generates Agenerated class from an annotated A class.
I would like to be able to do something like

```
AgeneratedInst.getFoo().getBar()...
```

In order to do so I have to specify the return type which is the current class I am writing... Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out, maybe it's kinda weird but it works.
I just have to specify a TypeName like this:

```
String generatedName = "Agenerated";
ClassName className = ClassName.get("", classsName);
```

then I use it as a return type for a method and it's ok